# What does superscript false mean?

Tags: logic, notation

I was reading a blog post and found a logic statement that read as so:

$  k^⊥ → k$

Do anyone know what is mean by this statement? (I read it here: http://logicaltypes.blogspot.com.mt/2014/04/h-is-g.html)

Comment: Can you give a link to the blog post? Without context, it's impossible to tell what that means.

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like this is related to the end of the *previous* blogpost: http://logicaltypes.blogspot.com/2014/04/g-is-for-godel-gentzen.html

Comment: I had read the previous blog post, but the author still does not explain the notation.

Comment: See [Gödel–Gentzen translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#First-order_logic).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a solid link Mauro Allegranza